# What is the status of Jordan's theorem in constructive mathematics in the language of locales?

Tags: gn.general-topology, curves-and-surfaces, constructive-mathematics, type-theory, locales

By constructive mathematics in this matter we mean [intuitionistic ZF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_set_theory#Intuitionistic_Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel) (*).

In the language of [locales](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locale), the Jordan curve can be defined as $f\colon S^1 \to X$ such that "if $U \cap V = \varnothing$, then $f(U) \cap f(V) = \varnothing$" (coincides with the classical definition for Hausdorff spaces).

So, is [Jordan's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem#Definitions_and_the_statement_of_the_Jordan_theorem) true for locales in constructive mathematics?

(*) I like Martin-Löf's intuitionistic theory of types more and it seems that in a sense "this is the same question", but I have not studied the type theory systematically yet, so I am formulating the question in a more familiar language.

Comment: You probably mean [Intuitionistic ZF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_set_theory#Intuitionistic_Zermelo–Fraenkel) by "ZF without excluded middle"? One has to be a bit careful how these things are phrased.

Comment: You could also just say that a Jordan curve is a regular mono $S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, couldn't you? I don't know about the local version, but you would certainly want the map to be uniformly continuous, or else some really strange things can happen (a pointwise continuous image of an embedding $S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ may be unbounded, for instance).

Comment: @AndrejBauer Locales have no points (added a link to the corresponding page in nlab)

Comment: @AndrejBauer Yes, I did not know that LEM follows from the ZF axioms for some classes of formulas, thanks.

Comment: What are dots? Do you mean points? I am familiar with locales, my remarks about weird things happening was about the non-localic version.

Comment: @EschatumVerus: Be careful with the statement “locales have no points”. They’re not *defined* in terms of their points, but many locales *have* points — i.e. locale maps from the terminal locale — and they’re a very useful notion in locale theory. (Nice question, by the way!)

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine I meant "in general, locales do not have points." I know that points are naturally defined in terms of locales, but didn't think about it, yes. Indeed, for morphisms from the $I$ to the $\mathbb{R}^2$, we can speak simply of "injections".

Comment: @EschatumVerus: Yes, sorry if I was a little nitpicky — I’ve just seen misunderstandings about locales and points happen slightly too often before!

Comment: Let's clear up whether we want an injection (mono) or an embedding (regular mono), and should we not use the circle $S^1$ as the domain?

Comment: @AndrejBauer And in constructive mathematics it is not possible to prove that for functions from $I$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ this is the same thing? (this is true in the classical for mappings from a compactum to a Hausdorff space).

Comment: @AndrejBauer In constructive mathematics, there is still a natural bijection between continuous mappings from the segment $[0, 1]$ such that $f (0) = f (1)$ and continuous mappings from the circle $S ^ 1$. Right?

Comment: @AndrejBauer Oh, but in order not to talk about points, it is better to change of course to a circle, yes, sorry. Thanks!

Comment: Some comments : Yes map from I to anything such that $f(0) = f(1)$ are the same as maps from $S^1$. Embeddings and Mono are the same when the domain is compact and the target is Haussdroff (because a proper mono is the sane as a closed embeddings). Finally, when talking about $I$, $S^1$ and $ \mathbb{R}$ you should make sure you talk about the "formale locale" (and not the spatial locale), OR that you restrict to uniformly continuous map, but there is no need to do both ( the formal locale are compact and continuous functions on compact are uniformly continuous).

Comment: Regarding the question it self. This is definitely not something that I have ever seen done, so I would be suprised if there was a constructive proof available. But it might be something we can reach using a Barr covering argument.... That won't prove the result constructively, but it could at least show it is possible.

Comment: @SimonHenry Are you sure about that?  I thought that $[0,1]/(0\sim 1)$ was not constructively the same as $S^1$, because it has a "bump" at the point of joining.  E.g. in a topological model, the continuous paths in the quotient have to stop momentarily when passing through the join point.  I thought to get $S^1$ you have to do glue along an open neighborhood rather than a point.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I'm curious whether anything is known about the point-ful version of this theorem too (with uniform continuity etc.)?

Comment: @MikeShulman : Maybe it is only true when using the formal locale and not the topological spaces and that's what you are refering too ? (I'm not sure about the non-pointfree statement) But as locale it is true : The map $[0,1] \to S^1$ is a proper surjection so it is an effective epimorphism ( even an effective descent map), and the kernel just identify the end points.

Comment: I'm also a bit puzzled, but my main concern is that you don't state the conclusion of the theorem. This is important since there are usually several choices when reinterpreting a classical theorem intuitionistically.

Comment: @MikeShulman is correct. To see more concretely, the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ is not the image of the classical parametrization $(\cos t, \sin t)$ for $t \in [0,2\pi]$ unless real numbers are dichotomous: $\forall x,y(x \ge y \lor x \le y)$.

Comment: @MikeShulman: In the effective topos every map $S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is pointwise continuous, and there is an embedding $f : S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ whose image is unbounded. So at least one part of Jordan's curve theorem fails (namely that one of the regions is bounded). There is a paper about [The constructive Jordan curve theorem](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rmjm/1250130636). It might be translatable to the localic version.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais what you are talking about is for topological space, not for locales ( an equalizer of locales don't have to be surjective on points)

Comment: @SimonHenry I didn't say anything about points. What am I missing?

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais The claim in your comment is correct but start from the assumption that the map $t \mapsto (cos(t),sin(t) ) $ ( $t \in [0,2 \pi ]$) is surjective "on points" (I.e. real numbers), while the claim I was making (and mike was answering too) is about this map being a proper surjection of locales (and hence the coequalizer of its kernel pair). Proper surjection of locales or coequalizer of locales don't have to be surjective on points.

Comment: @SimonHenry I'm still confused here. Are you saying that $(-\infty,0]\cup[0,\infty) = \mathbb{R}$ is always true as locales? That seems to contradict that the map from subspaces to sublocales is injective, which I imagined was always true.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais If you define the union as the pushout over singleton ${0}$ or as supremum of sublocales then yes : union of closed sublocale corresponds to the (closed complement) intersection of their open complements, and here it is clear that the intersection of the open complement is empty. I guess the problem is that as a subset $(-\infty,0] \cup [0,+ \infty) $ it is not sober ? (or rather that assuming it is sober least to the conlusion that it contains all reals...) I had never pushed that line of thought this far... Maybe Haussdorf $\Rightarrow$ sober is non-constructive ?

Comment: I believe I have heard that Hausdorff=>sober is indeed nonconstructive.

Comment: After more thought : If $(-\infty,0]$ and $[0,\infty)$ denotes the closed sublocales of the topological space $\mathbb{R}$ then their union as sublocale is indeed $\mathbb{R}$. What I can't quite figure out is whether these two closed sublocales are spatial or not. If they are it indeed means that any sublocale containing their points is $\mathbb{R}$ so that the set $(-\infty,0] \cup [0,\infty)$ can't be sober as a subspace. But, If they are not spatial, then you can interpret $[0,\infty)$ differently (as a spatial subpace) and I don't know if the union is $\mathbb{R}$ in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me first clarify some confusion in the comments to the original question. To be clear : I'm not at all saying the persons making them were confused, as far as I can tell all the comments were correct, my point is rather than the mixture of the "topological" and "localic" point of view created some confusion (which I might very well be responsible for), and I would like to clarify the distinction before we go any further.

The big point that need clarification is whether we talk about the "Topological space $\mathbb{R}$" which is constructed by starting from the set of (for exemple) Dedekind (continuous) real numbers, putting a topology on them and looking at the associated locales, or about the "formal locale $\mathbb{R}$" which is constructed as the classifying topos (or rather classifying locale) for Dedekind real number.

Many problems in non-localic constructive analysis (of the kind mentioned by Andrej Bauer in his comments) are closely related to the fact that topological space $\mathbb{R}$ is not (always) locally compact, so for example, not every map on it to $\mathbb{R}^n$ has to be bounded on $[0,1]$ or uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$.

On the other hand, the formal locale $\mathbb{R}$ is always locally compact. So if $I = [0,1]$ denote the closed sublocale $[0,1]$, any map $I \to \mathbb{R}^n$ (where I'm using the formal locale on both side) is automatically bounded and uniformly continuous.

In fact, the two definitions coincide if and only if the topological space $\mathbb{R}$ is locally compact and a map between the topological $\mathbb{R}^n$ (or open subsets of them) extend into a map between the localic version if and only if it is uniformly continuous on closed bunded subsets. So this really caputres the difference.

As the question explicitely refers to "the language of locales" I will be (from now on) only refering to the localic version when talking about $\mathbb{R}^n$ and its subspace.

Once we know that all the locale under consideration are (locally) compact and Haussdorf (By Hausdorff I mean with a closed diagonal), one can decude that all the important maps are proper from the fact that any map from a compact locale to a Hausdorff locale is proper.

In particular (and that is another difference between the topological and localic point of view), the map $I \to S^1$ that sends $t$ to $(\cos(2\pi t),sin(2 \pi t) )$ is a proper morphism, it is also a surjection (its image is a closed sublocale that contains a dense set of point), hence it is an effective descent morphisms and hence the equalizer of its Kernel pair. Its kernel pair is exactly $\Delta \coprod \{(0,1) , (1,0) \}$ (where $\Delta$ denote the diagonal), and so $S^1$ can be obtained by gluing the end point of $I$. For any locale $X$, a map $S^1 \to X$ is the same as a map $f: I \to X$ such that $f(0)=f(1)$. Note that - as observed in the comments - this is in contrast with what happen with topological spaces, where the map $I \to S^1$ fail to even be surjective on points constructively.

Finally, any map $S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is proper and uniformly continuous, in particular, any monomorphism $S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is automatically a closed embeddings (proper injections are closed embeddings). Now I'm completely convinced by the paper Andrej Bauer linked that the following is constructively* valid:

**Theorem :** Let $j:S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be any monomorphisms of locales (between the formale locales). Then $j$ is a closed embeddings and it's open complement $U$ can be written uniquely as a union of two opens $U = U_b \cup U_u$ with $U_b \cap U_u = \emptyset$, $U_b$ and $U_u$  inhabited and connected (and path connected) with $U_b$ bounded and $U_u$ unbounded. Moreover the image of $j$ is included in the closure of both $U_u$ and $U_b$.

I guess a complete proof of this would require writing a (short?) paper, and I couldn't find a simple enough Barr covering argument to get something like this (at least a cheap version of it) for free (at least not without doing substancial work first to, for example, to define the index of a curve at a point, but at this point, we can as well do the full proof). But I claim that the same methods as in the paper linked by Andrej Bauer [The constructive Jordan Curves theorem](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rmjm/1250130636) can be applied to prove the theorem :

The fact that we look at map of locale gives us all the boundeness and uniformity assumption they need, and because we look at the "open complement" of the closed curve, we get all the condition of "being at bounded distance from the curve". Finally, while all the proof in the paper explicitely refers to points, I believe they can all be interpreted as reffering to generalized elements : when they talk about taking a point in $U$, interpret this as working internally in the topos $Sh(U)$ and using the generic point of $U$ that you have there. Of course, in order to this, some additional work is requiered to show that many construction they do can be transfered from one topos to another (they are all "geometric") but I looked at it and so far I see no problem for doing this.

*Note : regarding the type of foundation/constructivism, I'll go to my safe place and say this is valid in any elementary topos with a natural number object. In particular it is a theorem of intuitionistic ZF. Though I'm sure if some care is taken when talking about locales, this can be made into a completely predicative statement as well, so weaker systems like constructive set theory or some form of type theory should be ok too.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarification, it is very helpful to me! I'll mark this as the accepted answer, unless of course someone posts the short paper :)